# Python cx_Oracle handle partition name in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run a SQL query via python cx_Oracle and have to use the partition name to select records from just that partition as follows -

```
part='P_000000000196000001'
cur.execute("select * from order_header partition ( :part ) oh", {":part": part})
```

but get the following error -

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/widget/backora.py", line 9, in 
    cur.execute("select * from order_header partition ( :part ) oh",  {'part': P_000000000196000001})
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-14108: illegal partition-extended table name syntax

Actual query is as follows -

```
select * from order_header(P_000000000196000001) oh;
```

Any suggestions on how I can include the partition name in the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot dynamically bind objects names (like the partition name in this case), only values. You'll have to resort to string manipulation:

```
cur.execute("select * from order_header partition (%s) oh" % ('P_000000000196000001'))
```